# When operator= is deleted, what function will be call in VS2013?

Tags: c++

In VS2013:

```
class A 
{
   public: 
   A& operator=(A&& other){/*...*/}; 
};
int main() 
{ 
   A a; 
   A b; 
   a = b; 
   return 0; 
}
```

this code can be run without any error in VS2013.
So, what function will be call in 'a = b' in VS2013?

Comment: This calls the assignment operator, not the move-assignment operator.

Comment: "This code" does in fact have errors: the "......" is invalid, and there's no semicolon after the class definition. Not to be picky for the sake of picky, but actual exact code would help to discuss exactly what you mean.

Comment: '......'mean something

Comment: This is difficult to answer, since more recent versions of MSVC don't have such a bug.

Comment: If you `= delete` a function, including operators, and you try to call it it will simply fail to compile. It won't call something else instead.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to ask.  In your code you are not deleting any `= operator`

Comment: the book 'c++ primer' saying like this: when you define move constructors or move assignment operators,the copy constructors and copy assignment operators will be defined as deleted.

Comment: VS2013 is old. Either upgrade or explicitly delete or define assignment operator to avoid the problem.

Comment: I agree with @Phil1970, VS2013 is has a lot of bugs with move semantics. Try upgrading to prevent learning it the wrong way.